# ListView DataTemplate in separate folder

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to learn programming apps for Universal Windows Platform. I'm currently working with `ListView` and I define its layout in `<DataTemplate>`, but the code is a one mess. Is there a way to define `<DataTemplate>` in a separate folder? I searched the net but I wasn't able to find a solution. Could you please help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: How does your DataTempalte look like? You can for example define a UserControl somewhere and then just refer to it in resources. You can define *DataTemplate* in separate resources file and then merge dictionaries in resources of app/page/listview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would always recommend creating a ResourceDictionary for this kind of thing. Here's an example setup:

Create a folder Resources > Add > New item > Resource Dictionary "Templates.xaml"

In your App.xaml add

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Templates.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In Templates.xaml you can add any template you want, like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:thestory.Resources">


<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemTemplate">

</DataTemplate>
```

You can now reference this template wherever you need it using {StaticResource ListItemTemplate}

Good Luck!

PS: I would actually also recommend doing the same for styles and other application wide resources like font sizes, brushes, backgrounds etc.

Comment: It's working, thank you ... But I have a button inside this template with onClick event which is not called now. Could you say why? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In datatemplate.xaml define datatemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DataTemplate>

    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In UserControl refer to datatemplate:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="<assemblyName>.Themes.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PerpetuumSoft.DataManager.UniApp.UI.Themes"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///<AssemblyName>/Themes/DataTemplate.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```